# Upgrade my safari browser in iphone iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

i want to upgrade my safari browser in my iphone.

is that possible, if so please let me know the way.

Comment: upgrade iOS. You can't update the bundled apps yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no.. the browser comes with the iOS.. so its only possible when there is a iOS update.